# Data binding in MVVM WPF OnButtonClick

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am using MVVM in my WPF application and I have a problem with data binding. I am considering binding user actions to data operations (in my case adding record to database). If I use heavy coupling between CommandClass and ViewModelClass everything works fine. My CommandClass in this case looks like this:

```
public class ButtonCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly UserViewModel _userViewModel;

    public ButtonCommand(UserViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _userViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _userViewModel.AddUser();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

My heavy coupling in ViewModelClass looks like this:

```
    private readonly ButtonCommand _buttonCommand;

    public UserViewModel()
    {
        _buttonCommand = new ButtonCommand(this);
    }

    public ICommand btnClick
    {
        get { return _buttonCommand; }
    }
```

My XAML coupling on button click (take a look on a Command section):

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <viewModel:UserViewModel x:Key="UserObj" TxtFirstName="" TxtLastName="" TxtEmail="" TxtPassword=""/>
 </Page.Resources>
 ....
 <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,231,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding btnClick, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource UserObj}}"/>
```

And I have such an output (take a look at Submit button): [Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv0uS.png).

After I make changes to my CommandClass and ViewModelClass (to make them more general and reusable), but leave my XAML coupling the same the Submit button becomes unavailable after runnig my application. After changes  CommandClass looks like this:

```
public class ButtonCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _executionMethod;
    private readonly Func<bool> _executeOrNot; 

    public ButtonCommand(Action executionMethod, Func<bool> executeOrNot)
    {
        _executionMethod = executionMethod;
        _executeOrNot = executeOrNot;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _executeOrNot();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executionMethod();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

My ViewModelClass after changes:

```
private readonly ButtonCommand _buttonCommand;

public UserViewModel()
{
    _buttonCommand = new ButtonCommand(AddUser, IsValidInputForRegistration);

}
public ICommand btnClick
{
    get { return _buttonCommand; }
}
```

XAML I leave the same. The output I have is next (take a look at Submit button): [WindowWithChanges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRPlA.png).

Can anyone provide me with some information, why button became unavailable and where do I mess up?

Comment: Can you post what `IsValidInputForRegistration` does? have you tried making it `return true` always and see if your button gets enabled by that?

Comment: public bool IsValidInputForRegistration()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtFirstName)
                   && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtLastName)
                   && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtEmail)
                   && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtPassword);
        }

Comment: This method just verifies that this properties do not remain empty before user will press Submit button.

Comment: "have you tried making it return true always and see if your button gets enabled by that?" I just tried, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try `IsValidInputForRegistration` to always `return true`. That will prove that your implementation of `IButton` (i.e. your `ButtonCommand` class) works fine.

If that works, what's happening to your program is the `IsValidInputForRegistration` passes the `state` for your `_buttonCommand` during `initialization` and it will stay on that state since it doesn't `query` if the `IsValidInputForRegistration` have changed states.

To achieve querying of states, you can implement the `EventHandler CanExecuteChanged` like so:

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

You can look into [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested(v=vs.110).aspx) for what `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` does. But I think the description says it all. :)

> Occurs when the CommandManager detects conditions that might change
>   the ability of a command to execute.

Comment: Brilliant! It works fine now. Thanks a lot. I'm new to MVVM and WPF so may be struggling on things like this.